# How to use filter in Count Q in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to sort a query set by its foreign key's number of objects that has been created in the last 7 days.

As in if there are three titles like:

```
Title one --> total entry: 100, entries in last 7 days: 5

Title two --> total entry: 10, entries in last 7 days: 8

Title three --> total entry: 50, entries in last 7 days: 2
```

I want them ordered like:

```
Title two > Title one > Title three
```

This is what I'm trying to get the above generator:

```
all_titles = Title.objects.annotate(
    num_entries=Count(
        "entry", filter = Q(entry__entry_date2__gte=make_aware(
            datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=7)
            )
        )
    )
).order_by("num_entries")
```

This is what my models look like:

```
class Title(models.Model):

    title_text = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    title_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    title_channels = models.ManyToManyField(TitleChannels)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_text


class Entry(models.Model):

    entry_title = models.ForeignKey(Title, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entry_text = models.CharField(max_length=2500, null=True, blank=True)
    entry_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    entry_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    entry_points = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    entry_readability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    entry_date2 = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.entry_text
```

Instead of ordering it by what I want, I'm getting a list that is sorted by Titles entry_set's length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) by default, sorts from lower to greater, so your order will be

```
Title three --> 2 entries in the last week
Title one   --> 5 entries in the last week
Title two   --> 8 entries in the last week
```

So I think you want to sort by descending order: `.order_by("-num_entries")`

I've created a small demo with data that should pretty much resemble yours to show the difference:

```
last_week = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
count_last_week = Count(
    "entry",
    filter=Q(
        entry__entry_date2__gte=(
            django.utils.timezone.make_aware(last_week)
        )
    )
)
q = Title.objects.annotate(
    entries_last_week=count_last_week
).order_by(
    "entries_last_week"
)
for title_entry in q.all():
    print(
        "%s: %s entries last week (total entries: %s)" % (
            title_entry.title_text,
            title_entry.entries_last_week,
            Entry.objects.filter(entry_title=title_entry).count()
        )
    )
print('----')
q = Title.objects.annotate(
    entries_last_week=count_last_week
).order_by(
    "-entries_last_week"  # Important '-'
)
for title_entry in q.all():
    print(
        "%s: %s entries last week (total entries: %s)" % (
            title_entry.title_text,
            title_entry.entries_last_week,
            Entry.objects.filter(entry_title=title_entry).count()
        )
    )
```

I added the total number of entries by title in the `print()` to show that all the values (count annotations) are properly calculated.

```
Title three: 2 entries last week (total entries: 50)
Title one: 5 entries last week (total entries: 100)
Title two: 8 entries last week (total entries: 10)
----
Title two: 8 entries last week (total entries: 10)
Title one: 5 entries last week (total entries: 100)
Title three: 2 entries last week (total entries: 50)
```

---

**EDIT** as per the OP's comments/[chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162771/discussion-between-isik-kaplan-and-borrajax) messages:

The possibility to pass filters to the `Count()` (or other annotations) was [added in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

In Django 1.11.X you *should* still be able to do this with Subqueries:

```
import datetime
import django.utils.timezone
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Count, IntegerField

last_week = django.utils.timezone.make_aware(
    datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
)
entries_last_week_sub_q = Entry.objects.filter(
    entry_date2__gte=last_week,
    entry_title=OuterRef('pk')  # The primary key of the Title objects
                                # where this subquery will be "embedded"
).values(
    'entry_title'
).annotate(
    cnt=Count('*')
).values('cnt')[:1]

q = Title.objects.annotate(
    entries_last_week=Subquery(entries_last_week_sub_q, output_field=IntegerField()),
).order_by(
    '-entries_last_week'
)
print("query %s" % q.query)
print('----')
print("Using subqueries:")
for title_entry in q.all():
    print("%s: %s entries last week" % (
        title_entry.title_text, title_entry.entries_last_week)
    )
```

Tested in a Django 2.0, though, not in a 1.11... **:-(**

Inspiration came from [here](https://medium.com/@hansonkd/the-dramatic-benefits-of-django-subqueries-and-annotations-4195e0dafb16) and of course, the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Subquery).

And also, maybe it's worth taking a look to [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for `Title.entry_set`, but using a [Prefetch() object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) so you can narrow down the `Entry` objects to be loaded by providing a queryset of Entries that have been created in the last week? Something like this:

```
q = Title.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('entry_set', queryset=Entry.objects.filter(entry_date2__gte=last_week))
).annotate(
    entries_last_week=Count('entry_set),
).order_by(
    '-entries_last_week'
)
```

This method (as opposed to the example with the Subqueries a few lines above) has not been tested at all, though.

Comment: Same output, sorts it by the total entry instead of the last week's count.

Comment: Are you `print`ing the number of entries in the last week? (the annotated field) Is that correctly calculated?

Comment: Yes I have an html tag that returns the number of entries in the last week, the return statement is length of the same thing in the above Q() statement.

Comment: A little visualization may help: https://i.hizliresim.com/nOYkyl.png these are all the titles and from top to bottom, it is in ascending order by its length of total entries.

 The numbers are generated with this bit of code: https://hastebin.com/ekurazosuy.py and represents the entries in the last week, I manually checked them so it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the links... It's difficult for me to reproduce, though... How about the HTML template that generates the list in the `.png` attached (the first link)? Is it possible there's some re-ordering happening there?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/exexijiveq.vbs view and the html, and thank you for sticking up with me for this long.

Comment: No problem! (I come from an area where people are known for their stubbornness, hehe) Couple of suggestions: In the `order_by` of the `q` (Line 16 of the hastebin) make sure it's `"-entries_last_week"` Also, within the template, can you print the `entries_last_week`? On line 41 in the hastebin, making it something like `<li>{{title.entries_last_week}} <a href=/{{title.title_url}}... the rest of the line... </li>` ? Just to see the number of 'entries_last_week' that was annotated to the queryset. What does it show? (this is just for troubleshooting... I can't spot anything obvious, though)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162771/discussion-between-isik-kaplan-and-borrajax).